# Why is it not true that if $\Phi \models \exists x \phi$ then there is a term $t$ with $\Phi \models \phi \frac{t}{x}$?

Tags: logic, computer-science, model-theory, programming

On [p189](https://books.google.com/books?id=rAy-NliGEPMC&pg=189#v=onepage&q&f=false) in *XI Free Models and Logic Programming* of Ebbinghaus' *Mathematical Logic*:

> In general, the following statement is false:
>
> (*)  If $\Phi \models \exists x \phi$  then there is a term $t$  with
> $\Phi \models \phi \frac{t}{x}$
>
> We  get  a  counterexample for  $S  = \{R\}$  with unary $R$,  $\Phi = \{\exists x Rx\}$,  and  $\phi  =  Rx$.

In the counterexample, why if $\{\exists x Rx\} \models \exists x R x $, then there is no term $t$   with $\{\exists x Rx\} \models R t $?

Thanks.

Comment: Well, what are the terms in that language? (There aren't many ...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, consider the terms in the language. There are no function or constant symbols, so the only terms are the individual variables themselves. There's nothing special about one variable vs. another, so let's just focus on $x$. Since $\Phi$ consists only of sentences, we have $$\Phi\models Rx\quad\iff\quad\Phi\models\forall x(Rx)$$ (think about the definition of "$\models$" in case we have formulas with free variables on one side or the other). But it's certainly not true that $\Phi\models\forall x(Rx)$: consider for example a structure consisting of two elements where $R$ holds of one but not the other. This structure satisfies $\Phi$ but does not satisfy $\forall x(Rx)$.

Comment: Thanks. What is the name for the process of "de-quantifier" such as the one in the quote?

Comment: @Tim I'm not sure what you mean - the shift from "$\exists x\phi(x)$" to "$\phi(t)$" for some term $t$?

Comment: yes.   ......  ........

Comment: @Tim I'm not sure it has a snappy term - maybe "instantiation by a term" (that would certainly be understood)? When a structure is being considered, "instantiation" can also refer to plugging in some element of the structure itself, named by a term or not.

Comment: Thanks. I am so sorry. I mistook ⊢ as ⊨