# Why is it not true that if $\Phi \vdash \exists x \phi$ then there is a term $t$ with $\Phi \vdash \phi \frac{t}{x}$?

Tags: logic, computer-science, first-order-logic

On [p189](https://books.google.com/books?id=rAy-NliGEPMC&pg=189#v=onepage&q&f=false) in *XI Free Models and Logic Programming* of Ebbinghaus' *Mathematical Logic*:

> In general, the following statement is false:
>
> (*)  If $\Phi \vdash \exists x \phi$  then there is a term $t$  with
> $\Phi \vdash \phi \frac{t}{x}$
>
> We  get  a  counterexample for  $S  = \{R\}$  with unary $R$,  $\Phi = \{\exists x Rx\}$,  and  $\phi  =  Rx$.

In the counterexample, why if $\{\exists x Rx\} \vdash \exists x R x $, then there is no term $t$   with $\{\exists x Rx\} \vdash R t $?

On [p69](https://books.google.com/books?id=rAy-NliGEPMC&lpg=PP1&pg=PA69#v=onepage&q&f=false) or [p66](https://books.google.com/books?id=rAy-NliGEPMC&lpg=PP1&pg=PA66#v=onepage&q&f=false) the $(\exists S)$ sequent rule says

$$  \frac{\Gamma \quad \phi \frac{t}{x}}{\Gamma \quad \exists x \phi}$$

Is this $(\exists S)$ rule the converse of (*) in the quote at the beginning?

Thanks.

I mistook $\vdash$ as $\models$ in [Why is it not true that if $\Phi \models \exists x \phi$ then there is a term $t$ with $\Phi \models \phi \frac{t}{x}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3808882/why-is-it-not-true-that-if-phi-models-exists-x-phi-then-there-is-a-term-t)

Comment: In a language where the only terms are the variables and a model $M$ and any variable $v$, $R(v)$  being true in $M$ means that (the $M$- interpretation of) $R$ holds for EVERY element of the domain, which doesn't follow from the truth in $M$ of "there exists $x$ such that $R(x)$"

Comment: You have already asked it some days ago...

Comment: The question is the same and also the answer: the existence of term t depends on the language

Comment: @Tim By the soundness and completeness theorems, the answers for the two questions are the same. (In particular, the $\models$ version + the soundness theorem gives the $\vdash$ version.)

Comment: @NoahSchweber without resorting to semantics, why is {∃}⊢∀ not true?

Comment: Why do you think that from “There is an Even number” you can prove “Every number is Even”???

Comment: This means that your inference is not valid and thus you cannot prove it in predicate calculus because the calculus is sound.

Comment: A good example from “traditional logic” showing what is correctly deduced and what is not is the following: from “Socrates is a Philosopher” to “There is a Philosopher” to “Everyone is a Philosopher “.

Answer (score 2):

In the signature $S = \{R\}$ the only terms are variables (because this signature has no constant or function symbols).  If there was a term $t$ such that $\{\exists x Rx\} \vdash Rt$ then that term would have to be a variable, say $y$, so we'd have $\{\exists x Rx\} \vdash Ry$, which is equivalent to $\{\exists x Rx\} \vdash \forall y Ry$, which is not true.

Edited to answer the edited question:

The sequent rule mentioned in the question is existential introduction: If you know that $\Gamma \vdash \phi(t/x)$, then you may conclude $\Gamma \vdash \exists x \phi$.  Intuitively, if $\Gamma$ has already found a term that can be substituted for $x$ to make $\phi$ true, then certainly there is something that can be substituted for $x$ to make $\phi$ true.  The question here is indeed about the converse, which is false for the same intuitive reason: Knowing that something can make $\phi$ true doesn't guarantee that there is a term that will always work (or even that the "something" can be represented as a term at all, as is the case in the example here).

Comment: Thanks. Why {∃}⊢  is equivalent to {∃}⊢∀, and why is  {∃}⊢∀ not true?

Comment: @Tim First question: By the inference Rule usually called "Generalization", which works in your example since $y$ does not not occur free in the premisses. Second question: answered above in the comments by Mauro A.